# Is it possible to create an ad-hoc standalone Gitlab Job?

Tags: gitlab, jobs

Is it possible to create an ad-hoc/stand alone Gitlab job that can be run whenever a user selects and start it? For example, can I create a job  whenever I select it(maybe through the Gitlab UI), a module displaying asking for API parameters, user inputs and then the job hit an API with curl with those parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your use case, but maybe it will help anyway.

There's a feature, announced in Gitlab 13.7 (Dec 2022), that lets you configure specific variables to be provided (with prefilled values) in the Run Pipeline GUI:

[image: Gitlab run pipeline with variables]

A simple `.gitlab-ci.yml` that supports this could look like this:

```
variables:
  # pipeline variables
  API_URL:
    value: "false"
    description: "API URL"
  


manual_deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "This is a manual deploy job that requires a variable."
    - curl -I $API_URL
  when: manual
  only:
    variables:
      - $API_URL != "false"
```

You can read more about this:

- in the [original Gitlab 13.7 announcement](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/12/22/gitlab-13-7-released/#pre-filled-variables-when-running-pipelines-manually)
- in Gitlab's [Run a pipeline manually](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#prefill-variables-in-manual-pipelines) documentation